# IP logger when a specific ip connects to the wifi

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I watched a video of someone coding a python script which detects if a specific ip joins the network. If the ip connects a message will be sent.

```
import subprocess
import os
from decouple import config

IP_NETWORK = config('My Network IP')
IP_DEVICE = config('The target device IP')

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", IP_NETWORK], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break

# the real code does filtering here
connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]

if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
    subprocess.Popen(["say", "Person just connected to the network"])
```

I get this error though:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 199, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 68, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: My Network IP not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

What did I do wrong or can this even work? The video where I found the script was from Kalle Hallden.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi Constantin: it would be useful to see the configuration file for this issue as well to confirm the error, but basically the setting "My Network IP" is not being read by decouple. Is it in settings.ini under the [settings] header as per the decouple docs???

Comment: Hi Jim. Where would I find the settings.ini / the decouple docs? The only decouple file I was able to find was a file called decouple.py

Comment: Hi Constantin. Decouple documentation is here: https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/... I think you need to review those documents as you're using that module to load the configuration when you call config(). It has quite clear instructions, but give me a shout if you can't work it out or post an example of your configuration!!!

Comment: So did I understand it right that i need to add a file called settings.ini? And in there I should add the information which is on the website? How do I create such a file? I'm using PyCharm (and VS Code) and on Pycharm I created a settings.config file and called it settings.ini. Is that right? Also do I need to create a database? I just want to have the program running and constantly checking if this IP has connected to the wifi. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

i have tried another way using the pyttsx3 module and it worked fine,

```
import subprocess
import pyttsx3
import time

tts = pyttsx3.init()



def sayconnect(x):
    tts.say(x + " just connected to the internet!")
    tts.runAndWait()


def saydisconnect(x):
    tts.say(x + " just disconnected from the internet!")
    tts.runAndWait()


count= 0 


my_ip= "insert you ip here"


while True: 



     pingip = subprocess.Popen(['ping' , my_ip] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     time.sleep(4)
     if(pingip.poll() == 0 ):

         if(count  == 0):
            print("user connected")

     elif(pingip.poll() == 1):

         if (count == 1 ):
            print("user disconnected")
```

i added the count to prevent spamming the same tts over and over again

Answer (score 0):

you need to actually put in the IPs, not just plain text.

```
IP_NETWORK = config('xxx.xx.xx.x')
IP_DEVICE = config('xxx.xx.xx.x')
```

i saw that video too, but he won't just leak his IP address :D

Edit:
i tried it myself, but it never worked for some module issues, trying a new method right now, so if this code worked for you let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the ip, what you'd like to monit, you can do it like :

```
import subprocess

def ipmonit(ip):
    pingIP = subprocess.Popen(['ping', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    pingIP.wait()
    if (pingIP.poll() == 0):
        print("Person just connected to the network")

ipmonit("192.168.1.1")
```

ping.wait() = waits the finish of the ping procces/ 4 pings
stdout=subprocess.PIPE = hides the output of the procces
ping.poll()  can be 0 or  1, if its 0  you have response, if you have 1 its not responding.
note that on windows even on Destination host unreachable will report UP!